# Why is 00 called 'double zero,' not 'double zeros'

Tags: plural-forms

Shouldn't 'double zero' be 'double zeros'? For example, we say 'double doors,' not 'double door.'

Comment: Sometimes we do say 'double door', counting the pair as a single item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double zero, double zeros or double zeroes?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61529/zero-zeros-or-zeroes)

Comment: We always do this with individual characters. The name "Jeff" is spelled "jay, ee, double-eff".

Comment: *We sleep in **a double bed*** (we sleep *together*). *We sleep in **double beds*** (we sleep in our own separate bedrooms, each of which has a double bed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't common to follow 'double' with a plural, especially not with numbers.

However, the reason we say "double *doors*" is that, in this context, "double" is the name for the *style* of doors. You could have two doors that lead into the same room but you wouldn't say the room had 'double doors' unless the two doors were together. If a room had two *separate* doors you would just it had "two doors". "Double doors" is a compound noun that describes a set of doors styled that way. Likely there are other similar examples too.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that "double zero" isn't often a mathematical expression. Usually, if we say "double zero" we mean 00, which (in a phone number or reference number) usually can't be replaced with 0 - just as if we say "double two" we very often mean 22, not 4.

Comment: Yeah I agree on the doors - *double door* is the style, and since there are two of them, if you're talking about both as separate objects you'd say *double doors*. *Double bed*, *double whisky*, *double trouble*, they're all describing a thing that's twice as much as normal

Comment: Notably the same convention applies to spelling. We would say that "see" is spelt s, double-e (never "double-*e*s").

Comment: Maybe the frequent need to spell things orally has led to a special idiom of oral spelling. If we were talking on the phone and I tried to clarify which word I had intended by saying "a t then an r then an e then another e," you would shout "Get on with it!" We just name the letters one after another, without articles or the word "then" or pluralization, and with this special rule about doubles, because it's efficient in that very common circumstance of oral spelling.

Comment: @rjpond As this isn't a maths forum, I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee thanks.  I have now voted for your revised answer.